# In Laravel Blade, Script @include works, but why @push not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I use Laravel 5.3,
I use laravel's default template(blade) to make layout and process my page.
Here i can't use **@push** to include my script,
but i can use **@include** to work fine.

What's the issue on these two implementations ?

Why its not support **@push**, but same script work fine with **@include**

**My Code :**

```
  @section('scripts')
    // My Scripts //
  @show
```

**While accessing,**

```
  @push('scripts')
     // My New Scripts //
  @endpush
```

This won't work for me.

But, if i try **@include**,

```
  @include('partials.scripts')
```

It's works perfectly !

what's wrong with this ?

Any solution for this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you render your section (using `@stack('scripts')`)?

Comment: Oh yah, Thank you man,
It's works fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`@include` is just for importing/including a particular blade file.

To render any code you've pushed to a stack you need to use the `@stack()` directive:

```
@push('scripts')
    // My New Scripts //
@endpush
```

Then

```
@stack('scripts')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `@stack('scripts')` was what we missed - cheers! It's not included by default in Laravel Jetstream.